# Update DataGrid in Wpf with databinding

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have DataGrid with dataBinding:

```
    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="colorGrid" Height="160" Margin="0,5,0,10" RowHeight="40" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
      <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Id" 
            Width="150"
            Binding="{Binding ColorId}" 
            FontSize="20" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Color" 
            Width="150"
            Binding="{Binding Color}" 
            FontSize="20" />
      </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

I set ItemSource:

```
colorGrid.ItemsSource = Colors;
```

After that I change element of my `Colors`. What should I do for update data in `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do anything, provided your bound types (`Colors`) implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and the collection implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  This will cause your `DataGrid` to automatically update as elements update.

(The INPC interface will allow changing a property within one color element to be reflected in the DataGrid.  The INCC interface will allow adding a new Color or removing a Color to be reflected properly.)